# Can't seem to find success with datetime python2.7

Tags: python-2.7

I have an application the does what I want with

```
date_time= "4/23/2013"
new_entry.set_value('lastdate', str(date_time))
```

But instead of hard coding the value I want to use the python 2.7 function for getting the current time.  I have tried several variations but haven't landed on success yet.

I am hoping someone with more experience can help me. One unsuccessful sample is listed below.

```
date_time= datetime.utcnow()
new_entry.set_value('lastdate', str(date_time))
```

Regards,

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is:

```
import datetime
datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%m/%d%/%Y")
```

If you don't want to do the double datetime each time

```
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
now.strftime("%m/%d/%Y")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> from datetime import date
>>> date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
    '05/22/2013'
```

The strftime method is also available on datetime and time objects.  The full list of formatting options can be found here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior